# linux script ends for 6-Nov-2011, but not for 7-Nov-2011 (looping through dates)

Tags: linux, shell, date

I need to run a specific command for a bunch of dates.  To that end, I wrote a simple script that will loop through dates, formatted as the command will expect them using the date command:

```
startdate=`/bin/date --date="January 22 2011" +%e-%b-%Y`
enddate=`/bin/date --date="7-Nov-2011" +%e-%b-%Y`
echo "Start Date: $startdate"
echo "End Date: $enddate"
sleep 5
incdate="$startdate"
until [ "$incdate" == "$enddate" ]
do
  echo "$incdate"
  incdate=`/bin/date --date="$incdate 1 day" +%e-%b-%Y`
done
exit
```

If I set enddate to "6-Nov-2011" the script will stop as expected after printing 5-Nov-2011.  However If i set enddate to "7-Nov-2011" as above, the script will print out "6-Nov-2011" forever.  I can't seem to figure out why...any ideas?
Thank You.

Comment: I think I figured out the problem - due to daylight savings time, incrementing 6-Nov-2011 by one day results in 6-Nov-2011 23:00:00 instead of 7-Nov-2011!  Suppose I can put in an "if" for this special case.

Comment: Perhaps you can add a mid-day hour:min:secs to avoid the daylight sayings time issue, then +/-1 hour doesn't make a day turn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured out the problem - due to daylight savings time, incrementing 6-Nov-2011 by one day results in 6-Nov-2011 23:00:00 instead of 7-Nov-2011! Suppose I can put in an "if" for this special case.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [at](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_at.htm) or [crontab](http://linux.die.net/man/1/crontab)